# How the socket server knows the client transform data over

Tags: web

In the socket level, when the connection is built, the server will continue read data from the socket,  my question is how the server  will knows the client won’t send any data?

Comment: Web? Are you talking about http server? Or just arbitrary socket protocol?

Comment: Yeah, socket protocal

Comment: What I'm asking, is your question about http or not?

Comment: I didn’t say it clearly , TCP protocal?

Comment: Not about http.

Comment: "I didn’t say it clearly" - in fact, you did not. Because you said "web server". That usually means "http".

Comment: I just corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how the server will knows the client won’t send any data

It doesn't. One option is to scan for pre-agreed-upon "end of message" byte sequence. When server sees this byte sequence, it considers message fully received. If there's more data in the buffer, it belongs to another message.

Or the client must advertise its message length ahead of time. "I'm going to send you X bytes now. Here they are: ..." The server then reads only X bytes from the socket and considers message fully received.

Take a look at [redis protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) for an example of the second scheme. It's very simple and fully functional. It is so simple, in fact, that a full client can be implemented [in only 20 lines of ruby](https://github.com/stulentsev/miniredis-ruby/blob/master/mini_redis.rb).